# sklearn.confusion_matrix - TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am trying to build a sklearn confusion matrix using the below

test_Y:

```
  Target
0   0
1   0
2   1
```

the data type of test_Y is

```
Target int64
dtype: object
```

and my y_pred is

```
array([0,0,1])
```

i then do my confusion matrix as

```
cm = confusion_matrix(test_Y,y_pred)
sns.heatmap(cm,annot=True)
```

but i get the error

**TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable**

Comment: Is it possible that you have used the name `confusion_matrix` for some array?

Answer (score 2):

You have reused the name `confusion_matrix`. You need to rebind it back to your function; this is one way:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

cm = confusion_matrix(test_Y, y_pred)
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True)
```

Comment: I get an error valueError :Classification metrics cant handle a mix of binary and multilabel-indicator targets